# How to make pagination in Vue with Apollo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuex, apollo

I got a little stuck with pagination with button Load more in Vue and Apollo, so the console gives me the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'queries'). Why loading more events is not working? Maybe I need an import or is there something wrong with the code?

**Vuex**

Action from Vuex that displays all events on the List component

```
actions:{
async fetchEvents({ commit }) {
      try {
        const response = await provider.clients.graphqlClientPortal.query({
          query: gql`
          query LiveEvents($limit: Int!, $page: Int!){
            liveEvents(pagination:{limit:$limit, page:$page}, order:{id:{direction:DESC}}){
              total,
              data{
                id,
                name,
                stub,
                description,
                mainImage{
                  id,
                  uri
                },
                location,
                type,
                layout
                chat,
                liveStream{
                  endsAt,
                  startsAt
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `, variables: {
            limit: 5,
            page: 0
          }
        });
        console.log(response)
        commit('allEvents', response.data.liveEvents.data);
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
   }
}
```

**List.vue**

```
<template>
// all events
<div v-for="(event, index) in this.$store.state.events" :key="index">{{event...}}</div>

// events from pagination
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post">{{ post }}</div>

<button @click="showMore" class="showBtn">Load more</button>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

data() {
    return {
      amountOfPosts: 7,
      start: 0,
      posts: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    apollo: {
      posts: {
        query: gql`query LiveEvents($limit: Int!, $page: Int!){
            liveEvents(pagination:{limit:$limit, page:$page}){
              total,
              data{
                id,
                name,
                stub,
                description,
                mainImage{
                  id,
                  uri
                },
                location,
                type,
                layout
                chat,
                liveStream{
                  endsAt,
                  startsAt
                }
              }
            }
          }`,
        variables() {
          return {
           limit: this.amountOfPosts,
           page
          }
        }
      },
    },

   showMore() {
      this.$apollo.queries.posts.fetchMore({
        // new variables
        variables: {
          page: this.start += this.amountOfPosts,
          limit
        },
        updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {

          return {
              __typename: previousResult.posts.__typename,
              posts: [...previousResult.posts, ...fetchMoreResult.posts]
          }
        },
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```